# Wordpress site team development

Tags: php, wordpress, git

I am starting new project, where 3 developers will work on a wordpress site. They will have local copies of the website and all code will be stored in git-repo. But I don't know what to do with database. Should they use same database on remote host or local copies? How to sync database data?

Comment: Depends on the project. Do you *want* the developers to be able to see /share data, or do you want them to all see the same thing? If the latter, use the shared database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case I would recommend having a centralized test server that stores a git-repo that manages the web directory on that server.  The developers can push to that server to test in the centralized space at milestones, and periodically take a DB dump from that server to use on their local servers.

Having all the developers use a centralized MySQL server is likely to lead to issues whenever the database is modified by code, and one or more developers don't have the code for that development.